# Windows Phone 7 ApplicationBarIconButton system style

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Is it possible to use PhoneAccentBrush on ApplicationBarIconButton?

Comment: Please add details on what you have tried so far.

Comment: The thing is, i can use all windows phone static styles on objects from Phone.Controls, but not from shell, it seems that ApplicationBar items are system controlled and have no Style properties. I've tried on Windows phone 8 emulator, maybe its only an emulator issue? In clean project when you add any control for example a button, its highlight color will not be system default Accent color like in system apps, it will be dark or light depending on theme color. Using of PhoneAccentBrush resource will fix it, but this not works with Application bar items. Sorry for my english, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't.

The application bar is not a silverlight control and does not use the normal conventions of databinding, brushes and other niceties that we are used with.

It's actually a wrapper for a low level shell component in the OS.

This article gives more information:
http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2011/07/05/solved-why-donrsquot-applicationbar-bindings-work-ndash-windows-phone-7-sdk